# Using Wi-Fi during lightning

Tags: safety, electrical

Is it safe to use Wifi during lightning or a thunderstorm ? How may I get electrocuted?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have anything to worry about. The lightning might fry all of your electrical devices that are plugged into the wall, and might cause some damage to your house around where the cables are attached to the walls, but you'll be safe unless you've wrapped yourself in live electrical cables or something.

While all radio waves are capable of inducing electrical current (this is why radio waves are useful for sending signals with), to do so requires an antenna of suitable length. Wifi operates in the 2.4 GHz range, which has a wavelength of about 12.5 centimeters, which would be the optimum antenna length for that frequency. Your body is much, much larger than that, and isn't very conductive, to boot, so any electromagnetic waves that get sent out when the lightning is coursing through the antennas and destroying the sensitive electronics in your Wifi hotspot wouldn't affect you.

Answer (score 1):

WIFI are waves which do not conduct electricity.

The only reason you might get electrocuted during a thunderstorm is if a powered device (e.g. laptop/mobile phone) is someway shortcut and you are part of the circuit (by holding it). Whether WIFI is used or not does not make any difference.

Normally batteries cannot give the power to kill someone.